# No space for sagemaker Studio lab to upload or download file

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

The SageMaker studio lab FAQ says there are 15GB space for each user, but I can't even upload or download a 900MB DataSet.
When I upload or download it, return

```
Unexpected error while saving file: sagemaker-studiolab-notebooks/preprocessed20152019.zip [Errno 2] 
No such file or directory: 
'/home/studio-lab-user/sagemaker-studiolab-notebooks/.~preprocessed20152019.zip'
 -> '/home/studio-lab-user/sagemaker-studiolab-notebooks/preprocessed20152019.zip'
```

and sometimes it returned "no space for device".

Comment: Hello SiYu, 
Can you share more detail? Did you upload from the upload button in the left hand side bar? Or you upload from terminal? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your storage is full, you can try deleting some files which are not required. I did this and it worked for me.

First type: `df -h` in your terminal.

You will get output something like this:

```
(base) studio-lab-user@default:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          27G   64K   27G   1% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm             4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/nvme0n1p1   50G   15G   36G  29% /usr/bin/nvidia-smi
/dev/nvme2n1     25G   23G  2.6G  90% /home/studio-lab-user
devtmpfs        7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev/tty
tmpfs           7.7G   12K  7.7G   1% /proc/driver/nvidia
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/firmware
```

As you can see here "/home/studio-lab-user" is mounted for users and available space is only 2.6 gb so to delete unnecessary files.

Type this in terminal `du -h --max-depth=1 /home/studio-lab-user`

```
(base) studio-lab-user@default:~$ du -h --max-depth=1 /home/studio-lab-user
14G     /home/studio-lab-user/.conda
249M    /home/studio-lab-user/.local
44K     /home/studio-lab-user/.ipython
16K     /home/studio-lab-user/.jupyter
8.1G    /home/studio-lab-user/.cache
4.0K    /home/studio-lab-user/.keras
4.0K    /home/studio-lab-user/.ipynb_checkpoints
0       /home/studio-lab-user/.nv
756K    /home/studio-lab-user/.config
0       /home/studio-lab-user/.sagemaker
0       /home/studio-lab-user/.virtual_documents
23G     /home/studio-lab-user
```

All files will be listed in size order, you can delete them using `rm -r /path/to/folder` like `rm -r /home/studio-lab-user/.conda`.

Warning: If you delete the /home/studio-lab-user/.conda you might loose your conda envs you have created.

And by this way you can delete other files and clear your storage , also after deleting you can check storage using `df -h` by typing in terminal.

Comment: You are answering the question "how to delete files". Please check the actual question again, you'll find it is a different one.

Answer (score 0):

are you still seeing this error? You may need to delete and recreate your account, checkout also this issue on GitHub https://github.com/aws/studio-lab-examples/issues/94